# Does Stata choke on matrices named "P"?

Tags: matrix, stata

So defining a matrix named "Z", and displaying its first element works nicely:

```
. matrix Z = J(1,3,0)
. matrix list Z

Z[1,3]
    c1  c2  c3
r1   0   0   0

. di el(Z,1,1)
0
```

On the other hand simply changing the name to "P" breaks the function of `el()`:

```
. matrix P = J(1,3,0)
. matrix list P

P[1,3]
    c1  c2  c3
r1   0   0   0

. di el(P,1,1)
type mismatch
```

Why?

**Update 1:**

While finding the above behavior (during a debug session), I reproduced from command line and from an ado file, then reproduced after clearing Stata with `clear`, `drop program _all` and `matrix drop _all`. However, upon restarting Stata, I am unable to reproduce the behavior.

**Update 2:**

At least I *thought* I used `clear`... further investigation shows that I can reproduce the behavior on restart if I have a variable with a name starting with "P" in memory. For example (starting Stata fresh):

```
. matrix P = J(1,3,0)
. matrix list P
. di el(P,1,1)
0

. set obs 100
obs was 0, now 100
. gen Parsnips = uniform()
(100 real changes made)
. di el(P,1,1)
type mismatch
. rename Parsnips parsnips
. di el(P,1,1)
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed Stata does collide with naming ambiguity in such a case as my second update indicates. Per feedback I just received from their technical support, using `di el(matrix(P),1,1)` to explicitly refer to `P` as a matrix resolves this issue.

Comment: This is indeed something new to me. I am getting the same results as you. Alternatively, you could use `di P[1,1]` to display the element. I've tested it with your example without problems.

Comment: +1 Oh, yes... it's Stata and not R or Python, so I totes forgot about subscription (I generally assume that Stata tries very hard to make things obscure/more challenging relative to other languages :).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
matrix Z = J(1,3,0)
matrix list Z

di el(Z,1,1)

matrix P = J(1,3,0)
matrix list P

di el(P,1,1)
```

Are you omitting information?

Comment: Difficult to say. My guess is you were using a macro inside `el()` and that macro once (de)referenced would result in something like `di el(P,"1","1")`. That would give the kind of error you report.

Comment: I thought that too, but I replicated the behavior using exactly the example syntax I gave above. Am about to edit my post again, and may have the start of an inkling of an answer.