# When is it illegal in Stata to call el(s,i,j) for valid in-range integers i and j?

Tags: stata

I use `matrix list` to show a matrix `P` that I have in a program:

```
P[1,6]
    c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6
r1   0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I expect the `el()` function to return the `i,j` element of my matrix `P` and I am trying to `display` this value (i.e. to print "0") using:

```
noi: di el(P,1,1)
```

However, Stata 15.1 comes back at me with:

```
  - noi: di el(P,1,1)
type mismatch
```

Why is this happening?

---

**EDIT:**

Reduced to a simple program:

```
program define MyProgram
matrix P = J(1,6,0)
noi: matrix list P
noi: di el(P,1,1)
end
```

And the resulting output:

```
MyProgram

P[1,6]
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
r1   0   0   0   0   0   0
type mismatch
r(109);
```

Comment: I tested this in three different versions of Stata and works as expected. Either you are not telling us the whole story, or you mis-typed something. Note that `noisily` does not require a `:` to work.

Comment: @PearlySpencer it's not from command line, but from within an ado file. The program is thousands of lines long, but this is precisely where it breaks. Thanks for the tip on `noi` I have updated a simple program reproducing the error.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Please see edited question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Stata choke on matrices named "P"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693145/does-stata-choke-on-matrices-named-p)

Comment: Which begs the question: Why did you post the same question twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment, you did not tell us that this was part of an `ado` file. Sometimes error messages like the one you report arise from conflicts between variables with the same names.

At first, this appears to be a bug:

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. 
. generate P = 0

. 
. program define MyProgram
  1. matrix P = J(1,6,0)
  2. noi matrix list P
  3. noi di el(P,1,1)
  4. end

. 
. MyProgram

P[1,6]
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
r1   0   0   0   0   0   0
type mismatch
r(109);
```

Indeed, if you get rid of the variable `P`, it works as expected:

```
. drop P

. 
. MyProgram

P[1,6]
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
r1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0
```

However, appearances can be deceiving. As the [Stata manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmatrixdefine.pdf#pmatrixdefineRemarksandexamplesNameconflictsinexpressions%28namespaces%29) states:

> *"...A matrix might have the same name as a variable in the  dataset, and if it  does, Stata might  appear  confused  when  evaluating  an expression  (an exp).
>   When the names conflict, Stata uses the rule that it always takes the data-variable interpretation..."*

Thus, **when evaluating expressions**, one must override this behaviour by explicitly telling Stata that it is dealing with a matrix. This can be done using the `matrix()` function.

In this case, line 3 in `MyProgram` should change to:

```
noi: di el(matrix(P),1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Pearly! The variable named "P" (actually any variable starting with "P") seems to be the culprit. Best.

Comment: Personally I never had this problem, as i always use `temporary` names in programs.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this behavior is not a bug: in Stata the name space for variables, matrices and scalars collide (with variable names having priority).

In order to specify that a name is a matrix in function expecting such while avoiding collisions one can make the name explicitly a matrix thus:

```
program define MyProgram
matrix P = J(1,6,0)
noi matrix list P
noi di el(matrix(P),1,1)
end
```

And then the output that results, even with variables loaded in memory starting with "P":

```
. gen P = 0

. MyProgram

P[1,6]
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
r1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0
```

Comment: @NickCox Not a bug! See my answer.

Comment: Variables and matrices do not share the same _namespace,_ strictly speaking. See the relevant section in the [Stata manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmatrix.pdf#pmatrixRemarksandexamplesNamespace) for more information.